# Django Update object only when foreign key object will change

Tags: python, django

I want to update my object's min and max price when Item's foreign key object(Currency) will be updated. In this situation it updates after every refresh of page.

my views.py

```
for item in object_list:
        if item.currency.id == 2:
            new_min_price = item.min_price * (dollar_rate.value)
            new_max_price = item.max_price * (dollar_rate.value)
            item.min_price = new_min_price
            item.max_price = new_max_price
            item.save()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use signals to solve this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/

```
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from . models import Currency

# This gets called immediately after any Currency object is saved
@receiver(post_save, sender=Currency)
def update_min_max(sender, **kwargs):
    currency = kwargs.get('instance')
    item = currency.item_set.get(id=2)
    new_min_price = item.min_price * (dollar_rate.value)
    new_max_price = item.max_price * (dollar_rate.value)
    item.min_price = new_min_price
    item.max_price = new_max_price
    item.save()
```

You might need to make some minor adjustments but this is the general idea. pre_save could be better in your case rather than post_save.